# Equivalent of Ctrl-a Ctrl-a in byobu (switching windows)

Tags: byobu

In GNU screen, I could type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> twice to switch between two windows.

In byobu, I can't see how to do that. <kbd>F12</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> doesn't work, and I can't find anything in the manual.

To be clear, I do *not* want to change the escape sequence to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. I want a key sequence that would switch between current and previous window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just moved my .screenrc out of the way and tried this.

On my machine (Oneiric) both <kbd>F12</kbd>-<kbd>Ctrl-a</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-a</kbd>-<kbd>Ctrl-a</kbd> worked exactly as I would expect.

I think you have another problem? Maybe something else is swallowing your key presses?

Comment: Hmmm.. I'm using it through putty, and now that you mention it, `F4`, `F3` doesn't work as well. I'll investigate and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

On my system, <kbd>F12</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> works fine.

Despite that, you can use <kbd>F3</kbd> and <kbd>F4</kbd> to move to previous/next window. You can access the shortcut list using <kbd>F9</kbd> -> Help.

Answer (score -1):

Toggle the menu by pressing <kbd>F9</kbd>.

Under *Change keybinding set* choose **screen-escape-keys**.

Comment: I don't see how this helps switching between two windows.

Comment: It enables the usual screen keyboard commands so ctrl-a twice works (as opposed to ctrl-a for start of line).

Comment: But that's not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for the F12-Ctrl-a to work.